# How do I break up a dataset in R so that particular values of a categorical variable are together, and I can then perform analysis of those values?

Tags: r

I'm doing a project for my stats class in which I need to make an infographic, and I have chosen a dataset involving all flights in the US in June 2016. All 500000 of them. I am trying to sort all of the flights by airport, then calculate the average delay and the percentage of cancelled flights by airport to create a "consistency" statistic to see which airports are the most reliable, and I need to do this with R because the dataset is too large to do anything in Excel. I can't use the by() function, because I cannot perform functions on other variables after categorizing the data. Help?

Comment: No clear why `by` doesn't work.  You can do something like `values <- by(iris, iris$Species, function(x) c(mean = mean(x$Sepal.Length), percent = sum(x$Sepal.Width > mean(iris$Sepal.Width))/nrow(x)))` followed by `do.call(rbind, values)` to get the statistics into a data.frame.

Comment: Not sure about the other downvotes but mine was for failing to provide a good description or example dataset and failing to show any coding effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A useful package for this may be dplyr. I'll use a couple of bogus variables from the included iris dataset to give an indication of how this would work. In your case, replace iris with your dataset, and change the various calculations to what you need.

```
require(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  mutate(# Calculate required variables at the level of your raw data
    Sepal.Area = Sepal.Length * Sepal.Width,
    Petal.Area = Petal.Length * Petal.Width
    ) %>%
  group_by(# Choose variable to group by
    Species
    ) %>%
  summarize(# Perform some grouping calculations
    Mean.Sepal.Area = mean(Sepal.Area),
    Mean.Petal.Area = mean(Petal.Area),
    count = n()
    ) %>%
  mutate(# Calculate required variables at the level of your summarized data
    Sepal.Times.Petal = Mean.Sepal.Area * Mean.Petal.Area) ->
  output
```

Comment: What are "dplyr" and "%>%" ? I'm running the code, and RStudio throws off  "Error: could not find function "%>%"" and "Loading required package: dplyr
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘dplyr’". How could I fix this?

Comment: dplyr is a package, and %>% is a way of passing the results of one function into another (also known as 'piping'). you will need to install the dplyr package first, then it will work. install.packages("dplyr")

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This would be much easier to answer if you gave an example of your data set.

If you have an airport name you can filter to that by running something like this. I'll just use msp as an example.

Dat[airport=="msp',]

If you have a variable called delay you can calculate the average delay by running

mean(Dat[airport=="msp", "delay"])

You could create a list of all airports and use a for loop to go over it to calculate all means.

Or, an easier way would be to turn it into a data table and run

Dat[,.(mean(delay)),by=.(airport)]